# Open window after script execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

Is it possible to open the window after the execution of the script expandNextLevel()?
I'm asking this because I don't want to let the client see the expand/collapse animation but just the treeview collapsed.
This is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $(".k-gantt").click(function () {

            expandNextLevel();        


            var windowWidget = $("#window");

                windowWidget.data("kendoWindow").open().center();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Act/load',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                    success: function (result) {
                    },
                    error: function (err, result) {
                        alert("Error" + err.responseText);
                    }
                });





        function expandNextLevel()
        {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

                var b = $('.k-item .k-plus').length;
                treeview.expand(".k-item");
                treeview.trigger('dataBound');
                if (b > 0) {
                    expandNextLevel();
                    collapseNextLevel();
                }
            }
            , 200);
        };

        function collapseNextLevel()
        {            
            setTimeout(function () {
                var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
                var b = $('.k-item .k-minus').length; 
                treeview.collapse(".k-item");
                treeview.trigger('dataBound');
                if (b > 0) {
                    collapseNextLevel();
                }
            }
            , 200);
        };

    </script>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way to do something like this is put everything in a hidden div, wich you will then show when you're done with the code execution.
You could also put a visible div with a rotating icon while the code is being executed, and hide it when you show the main content to make the users know something is happening.

EDIT:
I made a slight modification to the expand function, that should let me know when it's done executing the recursion, by adding an index I increment everytime. At the end of the function there is a code that will be executed only when the index is equal to one, wich means the first instance of the function is done executing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $(".k-gantt").click(function () {

        expandNextLevel(0);        


        var windowWidget = $("#window");

            windowWidget.data("kendoWindow").open().center();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Act/load',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

                success: function (result) {
                },
                error: function (err, result) {
                    alert("Error" + err.responseText);
                }
            });





    function expandNextLevel(var i)
    {
        i++;
        setTimeout(function () {
            var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");

            var b = $('.k-item .k-plus').length;
            treeview.expand(".k-item");
            treeview.trigger('dataBound');
            if (b > 0) {
                expandNextLevel(i);
                collapseNextLevel();
            }
            if (i == 1)
            {
               $.("#maincontent").show();
            }
        }
        , 200);
    };


    function collapseNextLevel()
    {            
        setTimeout(function () {
            var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
            var b = $('.k-item .k-minus').length; 
            treeview.collapse(".k-item");
            treeview.trigger('dataBound');
            if (b > 0) {
                collapseNextLevel();
            }
        }
        , 200);
    };

</script>
```

You should put you content inside a div

```
<div id="maincontent" style="display:none;">
    /*your content*/
</div>
```

I didn't test it but it should work :)

There is a better way to do this with jQuery.when, jQuery.done and promises, but I'm not confident I can give you a working sample since I never used those methods

Comment: Could you please provide a working sample of the first one?

Comment: @ArDevTeam updated my answer. The code is not so elegant, though

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, neither the .when method, which I already tried before.

Comment: @ArDevTeam Exactly, what isn't working? The widget doesn't show up? It's not hidden? Or are there errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.when(expandNextLevel()).done(function(){
    /// show window
});
```

docs https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/